# Struggling with asynchronous Node JS API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, express

I have just started learning Node.js and I am attempting a project which queries both the Factual API and Google maps API. I have been putting code together from several different sources and it is becoming a mess of callbacks. Also, it currently uses a for loop which means the asynchronous API call within the loop never gets run. I would be very grateful if someone could assist me with refactoring this code and also show me how to get the HTTP request to run within the loop.

Here is my current code where I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'legs' of undefined":

```
var auth = require('./auth');
var Factual = require('./node_modules/factual-api');
var factual = new Factual(auth.key, auth.secret);
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

var http = require("http");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var placedata = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='default.css' /> <table>";
    factual.get('/t/restaurants-gb', {
        limit: 50,
        sort: "$distance:asc",
        geo: {
            "$circle": {
                "$center": [req.query.lat, req.query.lng],
                "$meters": 15000
            }
        }
    }, function(error, result) {


        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
            var d = new Date();
            var seconds = (d.getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0);
            url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=transit&origin=" + req.query.lat + "," + req.query.lng + "&destination=" + result.data[i].latitude + "," + result.data[i].longitude + "&sensor=false&departure_time=" + seconds;
            var request = http.get(url, function(response) { 
                var buffer = "",
                    data, route;

                response.on("data", function(chunk) {
                    console.log(buffer);
                    buffer += chunk;
                });

                response.on("end", function(err) {
                    data = JSON.parse(buffer);
                    route = data.routes[0];

                    console.log("Time: " + route.legs[0].duration.text);
                    placedata += "<tr><th align='left'>" + result.data[i].name + "</th><td>" + result.data[i].address + "</td><td>" + result.data[i].tel + "</td><td>" + result.data[i].$distance + " Metres" + "</td></tr>";
                });
            });
        }
        placedata += "</table>";
        res.send(placedata);
        console.log(">> Home");
    });

});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting is coming from the google maps API [rate limiter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits). If you look at the results you're getting back, you're likely getting something like this.

```
{ routes: [], status: 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' }
```

You should check to make sure an element in an array exists before you access it to prevent this crash.

**First Refactor Pass**

```
var auth = require('./auth');
var Factual = require('factual-api');
var factual = new Factual(auth.key, auth.secret);
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var concat = require('concat-stream');
var http = require("http");
var async = require("async");

app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});


function getDirections(data, fn) {
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=transit&origin=" + data.originLat + "," + data.originLong + "&destination=" + data.destLat + "," + data.destLong + "&sensor=false&departure_time=" + data.time;
    http.get(url, function(response) { 
        response.pipe(concat(function(results) {
            fn(JSON.parse(results));
        })
    )});
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.write("<table>");
    factual.get('/t/restaurants-gb', {
        limit: 10,
        sort: "$distance:asc",
        geo: {
            "$circle": {
                "$center": [req.query.lat, req.query.lng],
                "$meters": 15000
            }
        }
    }, function(err, result) {
        async.eachSeries(result.data, function(data, fn) {
            var d = new Date();
            var seconds = (d.getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0);
            var directionData = { originLat: req.query.lat, originLong: req.query.lng, destLat: data.latitude, destLong: data.longitude, time: seconds };

            function writeEntry(directions) {
                console.log(directions);
                if(directions.routes.length == 0) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        getDirections(directionData, writeEntry);
                    }, 500);
                    return;
                }
                route = directions.routes[0];
                res.write("<tr><th align='left'>" + data.name + "</th><td>" + data.address + "</td><td>" + data.tel + "</td><td>" + data.$distance + " Metres" + "</td><td>" + route.legs[0].duration.text + "</td></tr>");
                fn();            
            }

            getDirections(directionData, writeEntry);
        }, function(err) {
            res.end("</table>");    
        });
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
```

I've made a few major changes here.

1. First of all I got rid of the manual buffering of the google api response by using [concat-stream](https://github.com/maxogden/node-concat-stream). You point a stream at it, and once the stream is through writing it passes you the complete response.
2. I changed the output from buffering (using placedata) to writing out directly as soon as you have the data. This means the page will start showing up much more quickly instead of waiting for all of the results to come back and sending it at once.
3. I replaced the for loop with async.eachSeries. This removed a number of bugs (closure bug, writing the end of the table before the rows, etc) and simplified the data access.
4. Check to see if the google maps call failed. If it did, try it again in 500ms.

I would **not** consider this to be the final version. There is still a lot wrong with this code, but it at least gets you closer to what you're trying to do. You should get a developer key to use with Google Maps. This should enable you to make calls more quickly without an error.

Comment: I've already checked for that and I don't think it's the case. The problem seems to be that the loop carries on going before the google maps API request has completed. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Also, if that was the case, is there any way to get round the rate limiter?

Comment: That is one of the many problems in this code. I'm working on a refactoring that will fix that among other issues. I've got a working version of the code, and that is the error I'm getting. Try changing the Factual API call to limit to one result and you shouldn't see that error anymore.

Comment: Yes, I think you must be right as the loop cycles twice before producing an error. It would be fantastic if you could refactor the code to fix this.

Comment: Okay, updated with my first pass through for refactoring. There is still a lot that can be done to improve this, but it's working.

Comment: Ok, I can't wait to see it.

Comment: Sorry, found another bug. Updated now.

Comment: Thank you for this, it successfully runs through the API calls so I have accepted the answer. Also, the results appear to be written to the screen erratically, so how would I incorporate CSS into this?

Comment: Don't worry... looks like I just needed to add `res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type" : "text/html"});`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an (untested) refactor. I am using the `async` library, specifically `async.map`.

[**async** docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#maplimitarr-limit-iterator-callback)

Now the loop which sends Google Maps requests has a callback. With a traditional for loop or Array.forEach, there's no async callback, thus you would have to roll your own way to do something later when your asynchronous tasks complete.

Other than replacing the for loop with `async.map`, the biggest thing I did was split some anonymous functions into named functions, to help reduce the callback hell. All the important bits are hidden inside `getRestsPlusRoutes`.

Compare the length of `app.get()`. It's easier to understand what's happening because you're only concerned with a single level of callbacks before sending a response.

I also separated the presentation logic (creating the HTML tags) from the data logic (the Factual and Google Maps API calls.) Now the code to get the restaurants and routes calls back with the data, so you can repurpose the function it at other places in your project.

I reindented to two spaces, personal preference to see more nesting.

I renamed the factual `results.data` to `rests`, so the more descriptive variable name helps document the code.

```
var async = require('async');
var auth = require('./auth');
var Factual = require('./node_modules/factual-api');
var factual = new Factual(auth.key, auth.secret);
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

var http = require("http");

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  getRestsPlusRoutes(req, function(err, restsPlusRoutes){
    if(err){ 
      console.log(err);
      return res.send(500);
    };
    var pd = buildPlaceData(restsPlusRoutes);
    res.send(pd);
    console.log(">> Home");
  });
});


// You can mitigate callback hell by declaring your asynchronous functions
// outside the code which calls them
function getRestsPlusRoutes(req, callback){
  // we have to pass in req so we have access to req.query.lat etc
  factual.get(
  '/t/restaurants-gb', 
  {
    limit: 50,
    sort: "$distance:asc",
    geo: {
      "$circle": {
        "$center": [req.query.lat, req.query.lng],
        "$meters": 15000,
      },
    },
  }, 
  function(error, result) {
    var rests = result.data;
    async.mapLimit(
    rests,               // For each item in rests,
    1,                   // with max 1 concurrency,
    getDirections,       // call getDirections(rest, done)
    function(err, mappedAll){
      // this callback executed upon all getDirections done(null, mappedOne)
      // or on any getDirections done(err)
      // mappedAll is an array of JSON.parsed bodys from Google Maps API call
      if(err){
        return callback(err);
      };
      for(var i=0; i<rests.length; i++){
        // Attach the `.routes` property of the google map result 
        // to the factual restaurant object
        rests[i].routes = mappedAll[i].routes;
      };
      return callback(null, rests);
    }); // end of async.mapLimit function call, including inline callback declaration
  });

  // declare the iterator function within getRestsPlusRoutes 
  // to ensure `var url = ...` can access `req`
  function getDirections(rest, done){
    var d = new Date();
    var seconds = (d.getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0);
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=transit&origin=" + req.query.lat + "," + req.query.lng + "&destination=" + rest.latitude + "," + rest.longitude + "&sensor=false&departure_time=" + seconds;

    http.get(url, function(response) { 
      var buffer = "",
          data, route;

      response.on("data", function(chunk) {
        console.log(buffer);
        buffer += chunk;
      });

      response.on("end", function(err) {
        if(err){ return done(err) };
        data = JSON.parse(buffer);
        done(null, data);
        // for simplicity, the entire parsed response is passed to the iterator done()
      });
    });
  }; // end of getDirections iterator function

}; // end of getRestsPlusRoutes


function buildPlaceData(restsPlusRoutes){
  var placedata = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='default.css' /> <table>";

  for(var i=0; i < restsPlusRoutes.length; i++){
    var rest = restsPlusRoutes[i];
    var route = rest.routes[0];
    console.log("Time: " + route.legs[0].duration.text);
    placedata += "<tr><th align='left'>" + rest.name + "</th><td>" + rest.address + "</td><td>" + rest.tel + "</td><td>" + rest.$distance + " Metres" + "</td></tr>";
  };

  placedata += "</table>";
  return placedata;
};


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log('Server is running');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks amazing, I'll accept this answer as soon as I've had a proper chance to look at the code. There seems to be quite a bit of a learning curve when dealing with asynchronous code for the first time.

Comment: Yes totally true. Sorry if there are any bugs. If you run into anything crazy i can help figure it out. This should be a good starting point for organizing async code. Ask in comments here if there is anything in particular you'd like info about, gl welcome to node!

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting the same error as before so I guess I might be going over Google's API rate limit. The error occurs after cycling through the for loop twice. Also, shouldn't I being seeing something being printed to the console from `console.log(buffer)`? Nothing seems to be appearing.

Comment: In the `response.on("end", function(err){` function, put console.log statements to check out what the response from google looks like. You may want to set limit:1 in factual for testing.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it goes over the query limit after 2 requests. I suppose the next question is how to avoid that?

Comment: If it's a rate limit, you could simply slow down the requests by adding another callback layer, this one a simple [setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg) that would delay the iteration loop from calling `done(null, data)` . @TimothyStrimple may have a more tailored solution.

Comment: I had assumed that setTimeout wouldn't make much difference because it's non-blocking? I'll try it out.

Comment: `async.mapLimit` with a concurrency of 1 should ensure that the iterator function is not called until the previous iteration finishes, and you manually call `done(err, mappedOne)`. So, you could call `setTimeout` from inside the iterator, then call `done(null, mappedOne)` or `done(err)` inside the `setTimeout` callback.